# how can match some string from content in array (Right to Left)?

Tags: php

I have music chord and lyrics like this :

```
<p>[Fm]      [Gm]     [Dm]</p>
<p>لورم ایپسوم ، لورم ایپسوم</p>
<p>[A]     [Asus4]    [Bb]</p>
<p>لورم ایپسوم ، لورم ایپسوم</p>
```

the "p" tags generated by wordpress editor for each line.

I collect the Chord with brackets by using :

```
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $content , $matches);
```

And result is :

```
[0] => [Fm]
[1] => [Gm]
[2] => [Dm]
[3] => [A]
[4] => [Asus4]
[5] => [Bb]
```

but I need to collect the chords from right to left and my array should be like this one :

```
[0] => [Dm]
[1] => [Gm]
[2] => [Fm]
[3] => [Bb]
[4] => [Asus4]
[5] => [A]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your exact input format? Does that include newlines? If so you could match the newline to find the subarrays and reverse those

Comment: each line is in a <p> tag , first line chord , second line lyric and ...

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56703151/edit) your question to add your complete input as code? Including those  `<p>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to capture a single line first by matching to: `(\[[^\]]*\])+(\<\\p\>){1}`
You can then take a matched string and match it against your expression: `/\[[^\]]*\]/`. 
If you take these secondary matches and put them in a 2d array you'll now have a object with this structure:

```
[0] => [Fm, Gm, Dm]
[1] => [A, Asus4, Bd]
```

Some (pseudo)code:

```
$outputarr = [];

preg_match_all("/(\[[^\]]*\])+(\<\\p\>){1}/", $content , $matches);

foreach ($matches as &$value) {
    $internalarray = [];

    preg_match_all("//\[[^\]]*\]/", $value , $matches2);
    foreach ($matches2 as &$value2) {
        array_push($internalarray, $value2);
    }

    array_push($outputarr, $internalarray);
}
```

You can now call the `array_reverse` function on elements `[0]` and `[1]` to get:

```
[0] => [Dm, Gm, Fm]
[1] => [Bd, Asus4, A]
```

And you can finally go from that to a single array by doing this:

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($outputarr as &$value) {
    $arr = array_merge($arr, $value);
}
```

This should give your wanted inside variable `$arr`:

```
[0] => [Dm]
[1] => [Gm]
[2] => [Fm]
[3] => [Bb]
[4] => [Asus4]
[5] => [A]
```

ps: I haven't taken the whitespace characters into account and `((\[[^\]]*\])`**`|\s`**`)+(\<\\p\>){1}` could be the better one. Furthermore this code could be improved by using `array_merge` and as such bypassing manual `array_push`

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = "<p>[Fm]      [Gm]     [Dm]</p>
<p>لورم ایپسوم ، لورم ایپسوم</p>
<p>[A]     [Asus4]    [Bb]</p>
<p>لورم ایپسوم ، لورم ایپسوم</p>";


preg_match_all("/<p>.*<\/p>/", $content , $nodes);
$final = [];
foreach ($nodes[0] as $node ) {

    if(!empty($node)) {

        preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $node , $matches);
        if(!empty($matches[0])) {
            $final = array_merge($final, array_reverse($matches[0]));
        }
    }
}
print_r($final);
```